# OOP & Forms, JavaScript Vs PHP

Tags: javascript, php, json, forms, oop

I want to build objects from HTML form data. The object or data needs to be submitted to a MySQL database as well.

Can I achieve this with JavaScript or should I be using PHP as a coding language? And finally, do you have a source I can read up on for achieving this?

Comment: Why not use both JavaScript and PHP?  HTML and JavaScript on the front end for user input / interaction. Then process, validate and store the data (in a db) with PHP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JavaScript and PHP are very different in that JavaScript runs on the client-side (the visitors browser) and PHP runs on the server-side (literally the server).

Depending on what you want to do with the form will result in a different answer. For example, if your form is used for a signup, then you'll want to `POST` the details to the server, but if you're doing validation on a form, then you probably want to add in JavaScript (with server-side validation too).

Comment: JavaScript has been running on the server side for quite a while now. That said, OP probably meant client side JS. Maybe this is worth clarifying.

Comment: I want to have a 'buyer' enter product requirements and a 'seller' enter product details. I figure I need to have the sellers item as an object and maybe even the buyers requirements. Then I need code to compare the two and list the matching buyers to the logged in seller

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum from the lack of specificity and generalness of the question I presumed it wouldn't be Node.js.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL usually runs on the webserver, so you'll usually need a server-side language (such as PHP) to talk to it. JavaScript usually runs on the client (i.e. in the user's web browser), so it can't make a direct connection.

The usual approach is to make your form in HTML, and optionally add JavaScript for client-side validation. When the user submits the form, the data is sent to the PHP script for processing.